# Dynamic Dates SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, recursive-query

I have the below data in SQL.

I need to figure out a way dynamically to get the next dates based the 2 values below. The remaining doses tells me how many dates I will need to find and RXDAYS tells me the increments in which to look for the dates

```
Date Shipped    Remaining Doses RXDAYS
2019-06-05      2               30
```

So based on the above I would find the date 30 days after 2019-06-05 and get 2019-07-05 and 30 days after that I would get 2019-08-04.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dateadd()`. This gives you the final date:

```
dateadd(day, doses * rxdays, date_shipped)
```

On the other hand if you want to generate new rows, then you could use a recursive query:

```
with cte as (
    select date_shipped mydate, doses, rxdays from mytable
    union all
    select (dateadd(day, rxdays, date_shipped), doses - 1, rxdays 
    from cte
    where doses > 0
)
select mydate from cte
```

For the sample data row showned in your question, this would generate three rows, with dates `2019-06-05`, `2019-07-05` and `2019-08-04`.

If `doses` has values greater than `100`, then you need to add `option(maxrecursion 0)` at the very end of the query.

Comment: This would get me the furthest date out but I need the dates at each increment of RXDAYS

Comment: @James: I was speculating about that. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you I believe this is what I need

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEADD()` function as

```
SELECT *, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(Day, RXDAYS, DateShipped)) FirstDateToFind,
          CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(Day, RXDAYS * 2, DateShipped)) SecondDateToFind
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('2019-06-05',      2,               30)
) T(DateShipped, RemainingDoses, RXDAYS);
```

---

UPDATE:

It seems like you're looking for generating rows as the following:

```
WITH Data AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM T
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(Day, (RXDAYS * (RemainingDoses - RemainingDoses + 1)), DateShipped)),
         RemainingDoses - 1,
         RXDAYS
  FROM Data
  WHERE RemainingDoses > 0
)
SELECT *
FROM Data
ORDER BY DateShipped;
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7cbbba37b5aaa04de94e0ed823a7fb59)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to make use of a numbers table (or create your own on the fly if you don't already have one). Assuming you can't ever supply more than 255 doses:

```
DECLARE @Doses table 
(
    RowID          int IDENTITY(1,1),
    DateShipped    date,
    RemainingDoses tinyint,
    RXDays         tinyint
);

INSERT @Doses(DateShipped, RemainingDoses, RXDays)
  VALUES('20190605',2,30),('20190704',3,24);

-- pseudo Numbers table
DECLARE @num table(n tinyint);

INSERT @num(n) SELECT TOP (256) 
       row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 
  FROM sys.all_columns;


SELECT d.RowID, d.DateShipped, d.RemainingDoses, d.RXDays,
    SubsequentShipdate = DATEADD(DAY, n.n*d.RXDays, d.DateShipped) 
  FROM @Doses AS d
  INNER JOIN @num AS n
  ON n.n <= d.RemainingDoses
  ORDER BY d.RowID, SubsequentShipdate;
```

Results:

[image]

If you only want the "next" dates and not include the original row, just add:

```
AND n.n > 0
```

Or, don't include `0` in the numbers table (though it *can* be useful):

```
INSERT @num(n) SELECT TOP (255) 
       row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
```

Comment: This is a pretty awesome approach and a way to not have to use a CTE, thank you @Aaron